# how can corenlp(python wrapper) handle non ascii string

Tags: python

I use Dustin Smith's Python wrapper for Stanford Core NLP tools v3.4.1

I put the word 'Víctor' into `corenlp.parse`. 'Víctor' contains non-ascii character. I would like to get the lemma of 'Víctor'. But when I put `corenlp.parse('Víctor')`. It gives error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128).

How can I change corenlp setting, so corenlp can handle non-ascii string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use unidecode before put non ascii to corenlp

Comment: You should add a short code example to your question so we can clearly see what you did to fix the issue. It's quite unclear at the moment.